# php preg_replace array but only in the initial string

Tags: php, regex

This scripts

```
<?php
$pat = array ( '/A/', '/B/');
$rep = array ( 'B', 'C');
print preg_replace($pat, $rep, 'AAB');
?>
```

I would liket to print 'BBC' ('B' replaces 'A' and 'C' replaces only the initials 'B')

But it prints 'CCC' ('B' replaces 'A' and 'C' replaces 'B' and the 'A' previously replaced by 'B')

If I tried something like this script

```
<?php
$pat = array ( '/A/', '/B/');
$rep = array ( 'B', 'C');
print preg_replace($pat, $rep, 'AAB', 1);
?>
```

But it prints 'CAB'...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If that really is all you want (only replace single characters), just use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$str = strtr($str, 'AB', 'BC'); // means: replace A with B and replace B with C
```

If you are not talking just about single characters, but about strings (but still no regex), `strtr` will still work:

```
$str = strtr($str, array('Hallo' => 'World', 'World' => 'Hallo'));
```

Comment: I read strstr but it's strtr. That's the good answer! Thanks!

Comment: @nikic: What should be the answer if regex is required?

Answer (score 1):

This should work :)
You just change it's order, so it replaces B before A, and that's it

```
<?php
$pat = array ( '/B/', '/A/');
$rep = array ( 'C', 'B');
print preg_replace($pat, $rep, 'AAB');
?>
```